# Wordpress giving 404 error for all pages except home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using wordpress for my project and everything works fine in the local and when I deploy that folder in the server home page is working perfect but when I click any link or navigate to any other url then it is giving 404 error.

--> I tried by deleting the .htaccess file. my current htaccess file is there in the server as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

can anyone tell me how can I avoid this 404 error for all the pages.

Comment: Have you tested re-saving your permalinks?

Comment: I removed the permalinks value from the phpmyadmin, now I'm able to access all pages except wp-login and wp-admin.php pages. why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dashboard -> Settings -> permalinks and click save. Though you shouldn't have removed the permalinks value from phpmyadmin, unsure what you've done there but that should fix your original issue.

Comment: but I'm even unable to login into Wordpress, because wp-login.php page itself giving 404 error. I have the access for the phpmyadmin what is the value I should place in the permalinks field.